# which of the following statements are true ? ..

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

consider  the  power  series

$$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n) !}$$

Then   which of the  following  statements are true ?

$1.$The  set $\{f(x)  : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$  is  bounded

$2.$The  set $\{f(z)  : z \in \mathbb{C} \}$  is  bounded

**My  attempt**  :$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n) !}= \sin x$

we know  that  $ \sin x $ is  a  bounded function $\implies $ option $1$ is  true

Radius  of  convergence  of  $f(z) $ is infinite $\implies $option $2 $ is  false

Comment: Right for the wrong reasons... $f(x)=x\cos x$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $f(\pi n)=(-1)^nn.$

Comment: okay  @DanielWainfleet You are right .I thought  that it was  $\sin x$ .I have made a silly mistake

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I am confused. $x\cos(x)$ is not bounded contradicting the answer to $1$

Comment: On silly mistakes: John von Neumann  was perhaps the greatest 20th century mathematician. His proof of a major result was destroyed when it was found that it rested on an accidental change of a $+$ to a $-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x\cos x$ is **unbounded** as
$-\infty<-x\le x\cos x\le x<\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb R$
$f(z)=z\cos z$ is a non-constant complex *entire* function and hence **unbounded** on $\mathbb C$